# Text labels outside ggplot piechart

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, annotate, geom-text

how do I put a comment outside a ggplot piechart? Ideally in the corner of a window.
Any operations including cartesian coordinates somehow ruin the plot. I just need a simple comment about the source of data.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `labs` function to your ggplot and set the `caption` argument to your desired text. The caption will show up in the lower right by default. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl))+
  geom_point() +
  labs(caption="Source: My Work")
```